# How to convert array of ints to string?

Tags: arrays, string, int, type-conversion, d

I need convert array of `int`s to string. Following code doing it, but in result I am getting unwanted symbols `[` `]`

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

void main()
{
    int [] x = [1,3,4,6];
    string s = to!string(x);
    writeln(s);
}
```

output: `[1, 3, 4, 6]`
How I can remove brackets without hack with `replace`?

Comment: You could always just slice it off...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe And looks like it might be faster than proposed solution with `map`.

Comment: Yeah, the map one would do a separate allocation for each element, whereas the single `to` call I believe does it all at once. Single call plus slice is surely the simplest way and possibly the fastest... though the `format` solution should be competitive too and more customizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it for example like this:

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;
import std.algorithm;

void main()
{
    int [] x = [1,3,4,6];
    writeln(x.map!(to!string).joiner(", "));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std.format`

```d
import std.format;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto res = format("%(%s, %)", [1,2,3,4,5]);
    writeln(res); // output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```